# move_base global planner plans outside static map

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, base-global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
The default global planner plans outside the static map i.e. unexplored area. Is there any parameter I have missed out?

planner_params.yaml

```
base_local_planner: dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS
recovery_behaviors: []
planner_frequency: 0
planner_patience: 1000.0
controller_patience: 1000.0
recovery_behavior_enabled: false
clearing_rotation_allowed: false
controller_frequency: 20.0
```

global_constmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 1.0
  static_map: true
```

Unfortunately during mapping, not all parts of the room was bounded by a wall i.e. black color cells in the occupancy map. The planner found a path that goes outside the static map from one end and then into the other side of the room.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174141/move_base-global-planner-plans-outside-static-map/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2014-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on which global planner you're using, but in navfn, the parameter is [allow_unknown](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn#Parameters)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2014-07-02**:
I am using navfn and I set it to allow_unknown as false. However, it still plans outside static map. I verified this parameter by printing it in initialize() and also viewing the potential that goes outside the static map.

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2014-07-02**:
Ok so when I use track_unknown: true and unknown_cost_value: 255 inside costmap_common.yaml, I can get what I want. If this is a necessary parameter, it must be added to the navigation tutorial

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-03**:
Great! Glad you figured it out.